# Field select error thymeleaf selector binding

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-boot, jpa, thymeleaf

Why th:field=*{platform} does not work

I have been tried to add th:field=*{platform.platformId} but it persist

This is the error

```
org.thymeleaf.exceptions.TemplateProcessingException: Error during execution of processor 'org.thymeleaf.spring5.processor.SpringSelectFieldTagProcessor' (template: "silicon" - line 343, col 47)
```

This is my controller

```
@PostMapping({"/admin/siliconAdd"})
    public String addOrEditSilicon(@Valid @ModelAttribute(name="silicon") Silicon silicon,BindingResult placeValidation,
            final RedirectAttributes redirectAttributes,HttpServletRequest request,Model model) {

        User user = (User) SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication().getPrincipal();

        LOG.info(silicon.toString());

        if(silicon.getPlatform().getPlatformId() == null) {
            silicon.setPlatform(null);
        }else {
            silicon.setPlatform(platformServiceImpl.getOne(silicon.getPlatform().getPlatformId()));
        }

        String messageString  = null;
        Date localDateToday = new Date();

        try {

            if(silicon.getId() == null) {
                messageString = "inserted";
                silicon.setDateAdmission(localDateToday);
                silicon.setStatusSilicon("AVAILABLE");
                silicon.setUserOwner(userServiceImpl.getOne(user.getUsername()));

                if(silicon.getUserRequest() != null) {

                    silicon.setStatusSilicon("ASSIGNED");
                    siliconServiceImpl.assignSiliconToUser(silicon.getUserRequest(), silicon.getId());

                }

            }else {

                messageString = "updated";

            }


            Silicon siliconAddOrEdit = siliconServiceImpl.addOne(silicon);
            model.addAttribute("silicons",siliconServiceImpl.getAll());

            redirectAttributes.addFlashAttribute("success",messageString);
            return "redirect:/admin/step2/" + siliconAddOrEdit.getPlatform().getPlatformId();

        }catch(Exception ex) {
            redirectAttributes.addFlashAttribute("error",messageString);
            LOG.info(ex.toString());
            return "redirect:/admin/silicon";
        }

    }
```

This is the thymeleaf part

```
<select class="custom-select" th:field="*{platform}" id="platformCurrent">
                                    <option value="">--Select Platform to Assign--</option>
                                                <option th:each="platform : ${platforms}" th:value="${platform.platformId}" th:utext="${platform.name}"></option>
                                                    </select>
```

How can i resolve this issue?

I want to get the entire platform without consult the database

Comment: What is the name of this thymeleaf page ?

Comment: it is called as silicon

Comment: Do you have any `GetMapping` to go to `silicon` page before posting data?

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this

```
<select class="custom-select" id="platformCurrent" name="platformCurrent">
                                                    <optgroup label="">
                                                        <option th:each="platform : ${platforms}" th:value="${platform.platformId}"
                                                            th:text="${platform.name}"></option>
                                                    </optgroup>
                                                </select>
```